# Why doesn't my matryoshka dolls of scripts work properly?

Tags: python, loops

I made multiple scripts which need to work one-by-one. The 2nd one is connected to the 1st one by inserting `os.system` inside a block of code that is an "if" statement.

My problem is that I've made practically my entire script #1 under an `if name == __main__` , I suspect it's because of that.

script1.py

```
import stuff, define functions ...

if name == __main__:
    do stuff

    if frame == 3:
        os.system("script2.py")
        # EVERYTHING ELSE UNDER THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK
```

script2.py

```
do stuff
if frame == 3:
    os.system("script3.py")
```

script3.py

```
do stuff
if frame == 3:
    done
```

I expected it to go back to the first script since by then, all of the os.system's would've been satisfied already. But I wonder how I would get it to work that way. There are still some important information below the line I indicated, that's why I need the entire thing to work.

Comment: This is really unclear and probably unreproducible. Where does `frame` get defined? It definitely is not inherited by subprocesses. (Running Python as a subprocess of Python is often the wrong thing anyway.)

Comment: Do your scripts have a `#!/usr/bin/python` line at the beginning, so they can be executed as commands rather than with `python script2.py`?